# Username in external link on Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, external, joomla1.5

```
http://webchat.quakenet.org/?nick=**insertnickhere**&channels=test&uio=d4
```

Hi i want to use this external link on my Joomla menu. But instead of insertnickhere i want to use the actual username of the logged in user. So when the link gets clicked by a user it assigns the username.

I tried to insert *{$user->username}*
But it only carried over *{$user->username}*, so it didnt work.

Edit: I inserted this link as external link to my Joomla menu, so that every user can join this irc webchat with his username.
This is a premade link from the quakenet irc webchat, where i changed the static nickname variable to *{$user->username}*, so that the username of the logged user is carried over to this link.

Any Idea or suggestion how I get this?

Comment: please provide some more information about where you are trying that code.

Answer (score 0):

First get the user object:

```
<?php $user = & JFactory::getUser(); ?>
```

Then echo the username in the url:

```
<a href="http://webchat.quakenet.org/?nick=<?php echo $user->username;?>&channels=test&uio=d4">link</a>
```